# How to implement push notification in a web app with multiple server?

Tags: node.js

I am working with node js to implement push notification in my web application. 
I have 3 servers for this application. In this case how can I implement push notification ?

http://www.gianlucaguarini.com/blog/push-notification-server-streaming-on-a-mysql-database/

Need to do this with multiple servers.

Comment: What are you pushing to, and what is it you're pushing?

Comment: http://www.gianlucaguarini.com/blog/push-notification-server-streaming-on-a-mysql-database/
need to do this with multiple servers.

Comment: Do you want every server to send a notification?  One notification per user?  Is every user connected to all 3 servers?  It's pretty hard to answer the question with the information given.

Comment: every user connected to every servers for different purposes. I need to send notification from every servers ,but not for same purposes. Eg: for user1  I am sending photo upload notification from server1 and message notification from server2. Then how can I manage this?